# Can I use software rendering on PC without any GPU (integrated or dedicated)?

Tags: graphics, gpu, shader

If there's not any GPU, how could I present framebuffer to the display? Or software rendering only means running graphic pipeline on CPU instead of GPU, and finally we still need a GPU to present the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering something in software just refers to creating the framebuffer on the CPU or other programmable hardware that does not employ graphics specific circuitry. The concept is not concerned with presentation of the results, you're still doing software rendering when you write the result to disk, stream it over a network etc.

Comment: Thanks. So, more specifically, if I want to present the results on a display monitor, I need a GPU, otherwise what I do is so called headless rendering, right?

Comment: I believe in the context of modern computing the answer is yes, there's always some kind of dedicated hardware (a GPU or a graphics chipset) that handles transport of a framebuffer to the receiving display via a protocol like VGA, DVI, HDMI etc. The closer you look at it the more blurry this topic gets though, especially when looking at older platforms.